# Jekyll Bootstrap—commenting function without advertisement

Tags: jekyll, disqus, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I have just started using Jekyll Bootstrap to blog related to my GitHub projects. I would like to have a feedback option, so I kept the default Disqus enabled. Unfortunately that pastes nasty "Around The Web" and "Also on jekyll-bootstrap" sections below my posts, the former apparently filled with unrelated sponsored links. I have a very strong hygiene when it comes to keeping my content spam free.

Can I remove the advertisement which seems from the Diqus script somehow? If not, are there other alternatives of adding a commenting function without advertisement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Log in to Disqus.
2. Select Admin.
3. Select the Settings tab.
4. Select the Discovery tab.
5. Change the Discovery level to "Just Comments".

Comment: Ok, I did that, also changed `short_name` in `_config.yml` to my newly registered Disqus account. Even though I deactivated "Discovery: Show links..." and saved my settings, nothing seems to change on the site, the sponsored links are still there. The links disappear when I run `jekyll server` locally, but not when I push to GitHub pages and refresh the remove site.

Comment: It seems it took just some time to adjust. The links are gone now. Thanks!

Comment: We're soon changing this layout, FYI. Instead of the "Discovery" tab you'll need to go to the "Ads" tab and then uncheck "Enable Promoted Discovery"